# Google AppEngine String to Text

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have an entity field which were already saved in datastore as String. String in appengine have limit upto 500 characters.

How can I changed it to Text and making all old value still available?

Comment: Keep in mind that TextProperty cant be indexed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend the following approach, especially if the code is in production:

- Introduce a new Text field in your entity.
- Write a simple migration code to go through each of your entities and then read the existing value from your String attribute and put that in the new Text attribute.
- Modify current code to write and read only from the new Text attribute.

The above approach will help you do things step wise and in the worse case of things going wrong, atleast you have the old attribute and the old values as is.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a db.TextProperty, but you cannot index this property.

To use it :

```
class Example(db.Model):
    ....
    content = db.TextProperty()



content_text = db.Text(example.content) 

or

example.content = db.Text(content_text)
```

Comment: In java you also have a com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Text : text string long Up to 1 megabyte

Comment: yes, the problem is that i need the new insert to have Text, and make the previous String still available for reading.

Answer (score 0):

For tasks like these, I've used a servlet with an action param to perform db operations. In your case, update the entity class, iterate through the entities and set your values accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Just fetch the field as Text. It will work. No need to migrate the existing values to a new field and all!